# How to add a seperate column instead of a row group in a matrix SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I am trying to create a matrix report in SSRS using Visual Studuio 2008 .
My reports are .rdlc reports 
This is how I want the report look like

```
Product Name |Year | Question1| Question 2| so on........
Test 1       |2012 | Response1| Response 2| so on........
Test 1       |2013 | Response1| Response 2| so on........
```

But my report comes as like this

```
Product Name       | Question1| Question 2| so on........
Test 1       |2012 | Response1| Response 2| so on........
             |2013 | Response1| Response 2| so on........
```

I am not able to achieve this the year column is adding a sub group 
but not as a seperate column

When I right click on the Product Name row these are the options i get though

[image]

Here is the screen shot of the report 
[image: screen shot of the report]

Let me know if any other option i have .

Thanks ,
Sravanthi

Comment: Can you post your report design?

Comment: Anup are you asking for the rdlc report file ?

Comment: Screen shot of report design tab, where you have designed matrix1. Have you tried the solution I mentioned.

Comment: Anup I am gone add the screen shot in the same post .

Comment: Anup I am gone add the screen shot in the same post .beside thank you for the reply.but that is not working in my case,when i right click it gives me only the options i mentioned in the post .I am using VS2008

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to troubleshoot if you post your report design.

**Method 1** Split Cells

Step 1. Right click on the detail row for `product` (where it says `Fields!Product.Value` or Test) and insert a row. `Insert Row > Inside Group - Below`

Step2. Right click on the data/detail row for `product` and you will see an option for `split cells`. Click on that. It will split the cells.

Step 3. Delete the row added in step 1 without deleting any row groupings.

Step 4. Run your report, you should see the changes.

**Method 2** Delete the columns and re-add them

Step 1. Delete `Product` and `Year` columns without deleting the associated groups.

Step 2. Right Click on your `Question` column and click on `Insert Column > Outside Group - Left`. Do that twice.

Step 3. In those newly generated columns add the Product and Year header and data.

Step 4. Run your report, you should see the changes.