# RDLC Matrix report move grouping column

Tags: matrix, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, rdlc

I have an RDCL Matrix report.

Generated in Visual Studio 2013.

In Asp.net MVC5.

I am creating the report for a database based on a range of dates returned in a recordset and bound at runtime to the report. Depening on the dates returned in the dataset the columns in the report are dynamically created (matrix report).

My date range will always be for a months duration so my report is very wide and space is of importance as users want entire months date range to fit on one page.

This is how my report currently looks(sorry i had to mask out data).As you can see i can only fit until the 23 October and then it moves onto other page. I need it all to fit on one page.

[image]
This is how it looks in the designer so you can see where the groupings are.

[image]

So in order to make it fit all on one page, i was hoping it could easily move the employee row group column above the data rows (only to appear once per instance of that employee) so it doesn't take up the space in the row it currently resides in ? This should allow me to gain a little space.

I have tried to moving this column manually or re-creating the grouping and making it a group header but then all employees appear in a list instead of at the head of each section. I have looked at similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020074/how-to-add-a-seperate-column-instead-of-a-row-group-in-a-matrix-ssrs-report) but it's not really what i need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider "wrapping" your dates columns? It would allow you complete flexibility on how big your date range could be.

Comment: Ive wrapped the dates fields as much as i can without it being illegible. I really need to move that Employee group above the grouping, Ive seen this done in reports before, so it must be possible?

Comment: Oh, I don't mean wrapping headers, I meant wrapping the whole report. Say, only allow for 20 dates columns in a header, and overflow should start with new header. Something like this: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/05/09/reporting-services-its-a-wrap/comment-page-1/ I had to do calendar report once that could show only tree month on one page width (with weekly breakdown), so I had to add top grouping criteria for imaginary page number. So, the first three month would get page number 1, second set of 3 month - 2, etc.

Comment: And then this was top level grouping for matrix report which I placed into regular table - because I didn't want report (new header with next three months) to continue on second page if space allowed to keep more than one on the same page. (my method is different from what described in the link)

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately the users want all the column headers to fit the width of one page.